# Which software is considered as an EVM Interpreter?

Tags: transactions, evm

I am reading an article which talks about EVM interpreter but does not provide the name of interpreter. Is solc an EVM interpreter?

Zulfi.

Comment: No. Solc is a compiler. You should post a link to the article so possibly someone can assist with intepretation.

Comment: Following link says that EVM is the interpreter: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/3k4h3w/basic_questions_about_the_ethereum_evm_and_state/.    I would provide more information below.

Comment: Following is the article's link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.03814, The confusing sentence is: "EASYFLOW extends the EVM interpreter by tracking the
propagation of taints during transactions execution." but it extends go-ethereum. So I can't understand. Somebody please guide me. Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In light of the comments and the linked docs which I haven't read in detail, I think the following might provide some clarity.

Ethereum is a novel design, so the following may be hard to process in one pass.

It is *modeled* after a simple state machine that runs assembler-like opcodes. This is a logical description of a protocol design. Ethereum is a protocol.

Any correctly functioning ethereum client must be able to *interpret* bytecode in order to form its own independent conclusions about the EVM state. There is no authoritative machine to consult. It's a logical design and each node figures out the state from the inputs worked out by consensus.

Solc is a compiler from more human-readable code to EVM bytecode clients like geth will interpret.

Hope it helps.